# XPath to select all sibling and children nodes until next occurence of next self enclosing element

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div type="chapter">
<head>Chapter I</head>
<milestone n="m_one" xml:id="ch1sc1" unit="scene"/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<milestone n="m_two" xml:id="ch1sc2" unit="scene"/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<milestone n="m_three" xml:id="ch1sc2" unit="scene"/>
</div>
```

is it possilbe using XPath to select all nodes between the first self enclosing element in this case `<milestone />` up until the next occurence of the next `<milestone />` element.

In other words select just the `<p>` elements (or any other elements that might be present).

EDIT: Further clarification I'm trying to select just the p elements that appear in e.g. the first milestone element up until but not including the next occurence of the `<milestone />` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a task like this would be better suited for the language you embed XPath into (e.g. Java, or PHP, or XSLT). Why? Because your XML data (I suspect it's TEI) is arranged in a way that makes it difficult to manipulate, for example because there is no nesting inside the `div` element. A higher-level language is better equipped to retrieve data that is not structured properly (i.e. the way you need it).

To give an example, in XSLT you could use a grouping mechanism (`xsl:for-each-group`) to start a new group when a `milestone` element appears.

In pure XPath, the following might work (I cannot test it now):

```
//milestone[1]/following-sibling::p except //milestone[2]/following-sibling::p
```

Comment: You are correct in assuming this was a TEI document. Your XPath selects all `<p>` ignoring the milestone elements but what I'm trying to achieve (I might have confused you; I've since edited my question for further clarification) is select just the `<p>` elements that are between the first milestone and the second (not the ones that come after the second milestone).

Comment: @Arko I am fully aware of this, but then the XPath expression I suggested was wrong. Try again, I have edited it.